# How can I get the proper permissions to post to a Facebook community page via my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have one app that I've managed to install to several of my Community pages (not people pages). One of them I did quite awhile ago and it has all the proper permissions so that the app can post to the community page wall via the php sdk. I need the same functionality for my other community pages.

Links I've found so far such as:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=APPID&redirect_uri=REDIRECTURL&scope=publish_stream

have just given me the error:

You are using Facebook as CommunityWallName
To access this page, you'll need to switch from using Facebook as your page to using Facebook as yourself.

and will allow me to personally accept the permissions but will not apply it to any of my community pages.

Comment: All the community pages I'm admin of have the app that I'm using to post to the feed of the one community page they work for. The only difference is the one community page that works has the "Publish content to my Wall" field checked under the app settings and this field does not show up in the edit settings dialogue in the app settings for any of the other community pages

Comment: I can go through all the steps to request an access token and use that token as a parameter in the api post to post to the wall but on the older community page I have that I had setup previously, it just has the correct permission and does not require me to get an access token to post to it

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the `manage_pages` permission.

See here for more details: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#page_perms

Comment: I have the manage_pages permission enabled for all the community pages I'm an admin for. I still am not authorized to post to those pages though

Comment: Can you make a test post from the Graph API explorer?

Comment: I can use the Graph API explorer and successfully post to my personal feed. It however does not work when I attempt to post the same message to my community page feeds (it seems to go through but nothing is actually posted).

Comment: Did you open a bug report? I've had some goofy things going on with my pages the last few weeks where I have all permissions needed, but some items were not returned that should have been in an FQL query. I opened a bug report and the problems resolved in about 24 hours. Conicidence? Maybe.

Comment: Well I know the app is installed for the pages I just can't figure out how to get the proper permissions on the app for each community page on which the app is installed.

Comment: I used: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID to install the app on all the pages I administer but not sure how to specify the permission i need to post